# How to count orders placed by a Indivisual customers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I have table

```
Order(orderid, customerid, billingcompanyname, billingfirstname,
 billinglastname, billingcountry, shipcountry, paymentamount, 
 creditcardtransactionid, orderdate, creditcardauthorizationdate, orderstatus, 
 total_payment_received, tax1_title salestax1)
```

**customerid** is a foreign key.

I need count of orders placed by an individual customer with the Company name and above all fields in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT o1.cnt, o2.*
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, customerid FROM order GROUP BY customerid
) o1
INNER JOIN order o2 on o1.customerid = o2.customerid
```

Or even better:

```
SELECT order.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid) AS cnt
FROM order
```

Comment: I want to display the other fields Order(orderid, customerid, billingcompanyname, billingfirstname,
 billinglastname, billingcountry, shipcountry, paymentamount, 
 creditcardtransactionid, orderdate, creditcardauthorizationdate, orderstatus, 
 total_payment_received, tax1_title salestax1) in the output.

Comment: @user1314348 Yes, these queries will select all fields by "order.*".  You can also select all fields explicitly if you prefer. (same result though)

Comment: But its not showing the no. of order placed by Indivisual customer.

Comment: What are you seeing!?  Either query should return every row in the table, but with the count of orders for the customer as "cnt".

Comment: Yes, I need query should return every row in the table, but with the count of orders for the customer as "cnt"

Comment: you should see the count being the first column:
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid) AS cnt, *
FROM order

Comment: @user1314348 dude, not sure what to tell you other than to look again, more closely.  It works.

Comment: The query given by you is working. But its showing the CustomerId repeatedly the number of times order placed by Customer. I want only one row for individual cusomer with the count Column for no. of order placed.

Comment: Ok, but now you have conflicting requirements.  How are you going to show a single "order id" in the query results, when there are multiple orders per customer?

Comment: ok. I do not need "order id". I need "customer id" and the count of order placed by that particular customer in a single row.

Comment: so you need to select just the count and customers?

Comment: Yes. And also remaining fields should be in the output.

Comment: The remaining fields of which table - the customer's or the order's?
in case of the customers it would be
SELECT o.cnt, c.* FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*), customerid FROM order GROUP BY customerId) o INNER JOIN customer c on c.customerId = o.customerId

Comment: Could you please tell me that "o" is used for??

Comment: @user1314348 those are just table aliases. In the above example "o" means the inner query, "c" means the customer table.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve such result you have to `GROUP BY` the `customerid` but you cannot have the `orderid` within the results set as the `COUNT` has to run on the distinct values of `orderid`.

Answer (score 1):

do you have the companyName field on the orders table? You should have a company table and a companyId on the orders table.

Anyway, in this scenario (and if a customers ALWAYS belong to the same company), you can simple do this:

```
select customerid, billingcompanyname, count(*)
from orders
group by customerid, billingcompanyname
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this.**

```
with customers as (select '1424' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, 'Petr' name_first, 'Kellner' name_last, 'Chicago' name_city from dual
union all
select '1425' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, 'Shelley' name_first, 'Birdwick' name_last, 'San Jose' name_city from dual
union all
select '1426' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, 'Morris' name_first, 'Moore' name_last, 'San Fransisco' name_city from dual
union all
select '1427' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, 'Shyam' name_first, 'Bajaj' name_last, 'Detroit' name_city from dual
union all
select '1428' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, 'Xu' name_first, 'Wang' name_last, 'New York' name_city from dual),

orders as (select '1224215' id_order, '1425' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '235' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224216' id_order, '1424' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '356' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224217' id_order, '1426' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '263' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224218' id_order, '1426' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '326' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224219' id_order, '1427' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '236' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224220' id_order, '1428' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '233' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224221' id_order, '1426' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '633' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224222' id_order, '1424' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '235' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224215' id_order, '1426' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '632' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual
union all
select '1224215' id_order, '1425' id_customer, '13-Feb-15' date_purchase, '236' amount_product, 'Name of Book' name_product from dual)

select customers.name_first, customers.name_last, count(distinct id_order) orders, sum(amount_product) total_amount
from customers left join orders on customers.id_customer = orders.id_customer group by customers.name_first, customers.name_last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL

To count orders placed by individual customers, we can apply count() operation with windows function and which will give us desired output:
lets try this:
as in the input we have  **customer_id** is FK.

To count orders placed by indivudual customer:

```
select cust_id,cnt as orders_cnt,
dense_rank() over(oreder by cnt as desc) as drnk 
from (select order_id,cust_id,count(*) over(partition by 
cust_id) as cnt from orders_table) as x;
```

To list customers details who had ordered orders in count wise/maximum orders:

```
select * from 
(select cust_id,cnt,dense_rank() over(order by cnt desc) as drnk from
(select order_id,cust_id,count(*) over(partition by cust_id) as cnt from
orders_table) as x) as xx
join customer_table c
on c.cust_id = xx.cust_id where drnk = 1
```